# Redirect to login route if the user not logged in Angular2 2.0.0-rc.4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

This is my html file

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Dohatec Data</h1>
  <div class="navLinks">
    <a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>&nbsp;
    <a [routerLink]="['/about']">About-Us </a>&nbsp;
    <a [routerLink]="['/price']">Pricing</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my RouterConfig.

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', terminal: true },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutUsComponent },
  { path: 'price', component: PriceComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];
```

I want to redirect the users if they are not loggedin in the /home route. Can I do it in the RouterConfig? I dont want to use  `canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]` because it restricts before the route

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.store the user in local storage or cookie and you can check if the user is logged in from there on ngoninit of your component..
on basis of this you can redirect to login page if user is not logged in.

2.you can make a variable in service to be true if user is logged in and on basis of this u can redirect to login page .

i hope this is what u are searching for :)

YOUR ANSWER :-

You can use a canActivate and canDeactivate property in your routes.. first of all set a variable named isLoggedIn as false and make it true on login and  u can restrict the user by this by adding canActivate method as :-

in your routes file third property :..

```
canActivate:[Authentication]
```

and import authentication from another file .....

```
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

export class Authentication implements CanActivate {

constructor(private service: Service, private router: Router) {}


canActivate() {

    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) { return true; }
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answers but that is what I have already done. Can I do it in the RouterConfig?

Comment: as angular2 in not stable till now and the team is working on it so i am sure they will be introducing this concept as we were able to do in angularjs...

Comment: But right now u have to do as mentioned above ..it is not possible to do it in routerconfig

Comment: Well I got a hack using `routerconfig` and `canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]`, So will post , and as I said earlier I already did what you have mentioned

Comment: this is  what you were looking for @pdfarhad .. i hope u like it :)

Comment: Well i was lazy to post my answer, but you already did. Yes i have done the same thing in my code, so accepting your answer